# Proxy for Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, proxy

I am looking for a basic open source http proxy server for Google App Engine.
Preferably written in Python. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

for just HTTP/HTTPS PROXY, try with this

http://code.google.com/p/gappproxy/

Answer (score 1):

SOCKS is not an HTTP-based protocol, so it's not possible to write a SOCKS proxy on App Engine.

Edit: Note I wrote the above when you were specifically referring to a SOCKS proxy.

Regarding general HTTP proxy servers, you can't really do *that* on App Engine, either, because proxies need to be able to accept requests for any hostname; your App Engine app will only accept requests for the hosts you're serving off it.

You *could* write an 'anonymizer' type interface on App Engine, but it's not a true proxy, because it will require rewriting URLs to work.

Answer (score 1):

For basic HTTP/HTTPS tasks use 
http://code.google.com/p/mirrorrr/

Here is a quick demo of using Google App Engine as a proxy server.

http://mirrorrr.appspot.com/